# Disable WPF label accelerator key (text underscore is missing)

Tags: wpf, user-interface

I am setting the `.Content` value of a Label to a string that contains underscores; the first underscore is being interpreted as an accelerator key.

Without changing the underlying string (by replacing all `_` with `__`), is there a way to disable the accelerator for Labels?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use a Label as opposed to a TextBlock?

Comment: Yes - `Label` does a lot more than handle the accelerators. Also applies to other controls (e.g. `GroupBox`) that can't be replaced by a `TextBlock`.

Comment: this is helpful about this topic:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452462/make-a-hotkey-to-focus-a-textbox-in-wpf

Answer (score 95, accepted):

If you use a TextBlock as the Content of the Label, its Text will not absorb underscores.

Comment: I just used this approach in my app and it worked like a champ.

Comment: Does not work if you want to retain an already assigned doubleclick event (TextBlock does not have it)

Answer (score 36):

You could override the RecognizesAccessKey property of the ContentPresenter that is in the default template for the label. For example:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
      <Style x:Key="{x:Type Label}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
              <Border>
                <ContentPresenter
                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                  RecognizesAccessKey="False" />
              </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Label>_This is a test</Label>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Just tried this, doesn't work, actually.  Perhaps it does remove access-key binding, but it doesn't prevent the underscore from being removed.

Comment: Just copied the code into Kaxaml and worked. Did you try as is or change it at all?

Comment: Works for me, but changes the way a label looks :(

Comment: @AndersRuneJensen Try using `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}"` to keep the styling set in parent resources

Comment: Am I the only one who's thinking that there's something wrong having to write half a page of XAML just to disable the accelerator key?

Comment: @l46kok most likely not. Reason behind it is WPF will give you a lot out of the box and when you want to change it you need to be very specific. Unlike pesky `WinForms` where everything is in code behind.

Comment: Microsoft's official documentation doesn't show this, but I believe this should actually have `<Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">`. Without this, the padding is not incorporated and the visual appearance of the `Label` is different with this template as compared to the default.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `<TextBlock> ... </TextBlock>`
instead of `<Label> ... </Label>` to print the exact text, which is having underscores.

Answer (score 0):

Why not like this?

```
public partial class LabelEx : Label
    {
        public bool PreventAccessKey { get; set; } = true;

        public LabelEx()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public new object Content
        {
            get
            {
                var content = base.Content;
                if (content == null || !(content is string))
                    return content;

                return PreventAccessKey ?
                    (content as string).Replace("__", "_") : content;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value == null || !(value is string))
                {
                    base.Content = value;
                    return;
                }

                base.Content = PreventAccessKey ?
                    (value as string).Replace("_", "__") : value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not goog solution. Sometimes string has more than one underscore and WPF does not display only the first of them. This solution duplicates all underscores and can end up with duplicate underscore displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Please check my solution for both `Label` and `Button` control provided here on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117335/underscores-not-displayed-in-wpf/78097884#78097884)