# Make a "hotkey" to focus a TextBox in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, hotkeys

I am trying to make a hot key (ie Ctrl + Y) that will change the focus to a text box.

I am a transplant from Delphi, and this is confusing me.  In Delphi 5 this was so, **so** easy.  (On the caption of the label you could just add an & before the letter you want to make the hot key.  After you point the label at the TextBox the hotkey would work.)

For WPF, I am seeing horrific examples in WPF involving calling out to Win32 calls or making a command for each hotkey (and other such heavy implementations).

I find it hard to believe that an IDE and Languange version that was new in **1999** (Delphi 5) has a better system (than WPF) for something as simple as Hotkeys.

Surely I am missing something.  If you know, please tell me what it is.

Comment: may be this thread is helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361350/keyboard-shortcuts-in-wpf

Comment: @Habib.OSU - It looks like you can use an _ instead of an &.  But how do you connect the label to the TextBox?  (And I tried putting an underscore in my label and it just printed the _).  (The rest of the question seems to discuss using command for hot keys.  I would like to avoid that if I can (I will have a lot of controls and wiring them all up with commands seems like overkill.))

Comment: @Habib.OSU - I found the answer I was looking for.  If you are interested you can see it posted below.

Answer (score 27):

So, I should have kept looking harder.  I got it shortly after asking this question.

They way you do this is that you create a label and set its Content (something like this `Content="_Years Of Service"`)

You then bind the Label's Target to a text box.  (`Target="{Binding ElementName=SomeTextBox}"`)

Now if you press Alt + Y it will move the focus to SomeTextBox.

Here is the full binding:

```
<Label Content="_Label" Target="{Binding ElementName=SomeTextBox}" />
<TextBox Name="SomeTextBox" />
```

Comment: Except that if you are assigning the string from the code, using `SomeLabel.Content = "_Label";`, the underline will be displayed as-is. The correct code is something like `SomeLabel.Content = new AccessText { Text = "_Label" };`

Answer (score 0):

Method-1:

Place underscore _ in front of the letter that you want to be the Hotkey in XAML.

Method-2:

Using code-behind you have to use the `AccessText` control as it is responsible for displaying an underscore under the mnemonic character (indicating an access key or hotkey) and recognising the hotkey.

**Note:** Sometime underscore under HotKey are not visible until you press the `ALT` key

Output:
[image]

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="EmptyWPFApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid >
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="_Area" Target="{Binding ElementName=T1}"/>
            <TextBox Name="T1">Press ALT+A to get focus</TextBox>
            <Label Content="A_bout" Target="{Binding ElementName=T2}"/>
            <TextBox Name="T2">Press ALT+B to get focus</TextBox>
            <Label x:Name="Label3" Target="{Binding ElementName=T3}"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="T3">Press ALT+C to get focus</TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
namespace EmptyWPFApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Label3.Content = new AccessText { Text = "Atta_ck" };
        }
    }
}
```