# Dont treat underscore as Alt in context menu

Tags: c#, contextmenu, itemtemplate

I am trying to populate my `ConextMenu` in code. I am adding some `MenuItems` in it. A `MenuItem` contains a string and event. So problem I am facing is that if the string contains underscore (_) then menu treats it as alt key. So in context menu I see character underlined which is after underscore.

```
e.g. MenuItem.Header = "Some Command_With"
Output = "Some CommandWith" (Where W of With is underlined)
```

Here is the code.

```
var menuName = Some String Generated on run time;
var contextMenu = GetContextMenu();
var menuItem = new MenuItem { Header = menuName };
contextMenu.Items.Add(menuItem);
```

Someone told me that I can set MenuItem template. But I am not sure how it can be done.

Comment: You can try the following

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40733/disable-wpf-label-accelerator-key-text-underscore-is-missing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a double underscore, that will be treated like a single underscore.

Comment: Is there any other way of doing this? I know this will work but I am not convinced to use this solution.

Comment: I am not aware of any other solution. Besides, it's the official solution to the problem - so why not use it? it will likely have the least problems down the road.

Comment: Is it? I will use it then.

Comment: I cannot find any direct links to MS which show this, but all books about WPF mention it, so it's likely official. The offical link is likely buried under the 200000 stackoverflow questions ;)

Comment: @ChristianSauer 8000000 :D