# WPF '_' character in Property-Binding does not work

Tags: wpf, binding

On the MainWindow of my WPF application I have a simple listBox that is databound to an ObservableCollection. The ObservableCollection contains members of a simple "Product" class with one string-property. The goal is to show the text that is stored in the "PName" property of all Products of the ObservableCollection.

The MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="BindingCheck.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindingCheck"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="listBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label FontSize="26" Content="{Binding Path=PName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

The MainWindow.Xaml.Cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;


namespace BindingCheck
{
    public class Product
    {
        private string pName;

        public string PName
        {
            get { return pName; }
        }

        public Product(string pname)
        {
            pName = pname;
        }
    }
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Product> products;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
            products.Add(new Product("Toaster"));
            products.Add(new Product("Big_Toaster"));
            products.Add(new Product("Very_Big_Toaster"));
            this.DataContext = products;
        }
    }
}
```

And now my question: Why is only every second '_' character shown in the listBox output? The Output-Items should be: "Toaster", "Big_Toaster" and "Very_Big_Toaster" but however I get another output:

[Output-Items in listBox: Toaster, BigToaster, VeryBig_Toaster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfxgS.png)

Comment: This is a designed behavior. See: [this link on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40733/disable-wpf-label-accelerator-key-text-underscore-is-missing)

Comment: Thanks! That solves my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below code:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Label Content="_first_second" Target="{Binding ElementName=txtbox}"/>
    <TextBox Name="txtbox" Width="100" Height="50"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Now after the screen is `Loaded` press key 'f' any you'll see the `Focus` is set in the `TextBox`.

> Cause the the content of Label is treated as `AccessText` for `Label`
>   here and according to `AccessText` definition  first '*' `char` means
>   the `Accesskey` to element and '*' is not visible.

**use below links for ref:**

[MSDN on AccessText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.accesstext(v=vs.110).aspx)

[AccessText example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/wpf-accesstext/)

Comment: Thanks for reply! In my case is was much easier to replace the Label in the DataTemplate with a TextBlock (like swiszcz mentioned before).

Comment: @User95 yes. but your question was only why is that happening? that's why I didn't put a replacement XAML for your problme..

Comment: aha ok. I misunderstood your answer. Then you're right ;)