# WPF , UI Cannot display string with char : '_' correct

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I meet a very strange thing when I try to display string which include char '*' using WPF data binding.
Here is my description. I put 8 .txt files in a folder like follow picture.These files' name are different by using '*'. I make them different file size.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oPXc.png)

In my Application, I get file name by using code :

```
//Get all FileInfo object
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(LocalDir);
FileInfo[] files = directoryInfo.GetFiles(LocalFileMask);
...
foreach (var i in files)
...
FileName = i.Name,
...
```

But my UI Cannot display filename correct, like in picture 2 :
[image]

Your can see the diffrent between folder and UI view.
And I am very sure that they are right in code(see statusBar) , just something wrong with Label or TreeviewItem Content(Data Binding with string:FileName) Display.
Maybe change a property of UI element will fix this issue.
Can anyone give me some advise?

Comment: Seems like StackOverFlow either correctly display _ ?

Comment: String which StartWith(underline char) or EndWith(underline char) has this issue.

Comment: Use TextBlock not Lable . Find it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40733/disable-wpf-label-accelerator-key-text-underscore-is-missing